# Python 2.7 list of bytes to signed int32

Tags: python-2.7

In Python 2.7, how do I convert a list of 4 small ints (0-255) representing byte values to a single signed int32?

Alternately how do I go from an int to a binary string (0x11 --> '\x11') so I can use `struct.unpack()`.

Examples:

```
[0x87, 0x65, 0x43, 0x21] --> -2023406815
[0xFF] --> -1
[0xFF] --> '\xFF' --> -1 (via struct.unpack('<b', '\xFF'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert integer to single-character string, you may use built-in `chr` function.

```
chr(0xFF) # returns: '\xff'
```

Demo with `struct.unpack`:

```
struct.unpack('<b', chr(0xFF))  # returns: (-1,)
```

Comment: Awesome!  That's the piece I was missing!

Comment: For posterity: `struct.unpack("<i", "".join(chr(b) for b in bytes[:4]))[0]`